# Can I use Asp.net control in a SharePoint2010 webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint development, I am using VS2010 and SharePoint2010.

I am wondering whether there is a restriction using a asp.net ListView in a SharePoint web part control.  Because for some reason the intelliSense does not provide me ListView, just a GridView

Thanks

Comment: Do you need some further informations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Parts in SharePoint are ASP.NET Web Parts. So you can freely use without any restrictions the ASP.NET Controls.

The Code Behind might use the SharePoint API but everything you can do is provided by ASP.NET.

`Edit:`

Are you missing an Reference for the ListView ? You need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions in order to use the ListView

Answer (score 0):

There is not such kind of restriction in SharePoint. You can use any kind of asp.net control in SharePoint.
For ListView intelliSense, you need to register system.web.extensions in your control or webpart before using ListView.

**Please copy below code for register Library:**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```